# WBR tag breaking hyperlinks

Tags: html

I was investigating the cause of hyperlinks breaking on a friend's website. She copies over her content from email and pastes it in the Wordpress editor. In a few articles, the content between the a tags has wbr in it and that seems to break the hyperlinks. You can find it on http://chandni.org/information-about-awards-scholarships-and-more/
In case it's fixed  by the time you see the thread,
the copied content

```
<a href="http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/faqenglish.html" target="_blank">http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/<wbr />faqenglish.html</a>
```

what is shown by wordpress

```
<a href="http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/faqenglish.html" target="_blank" rel="external nofollow" title="" class="ext-link"></a><a href="http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/" rel="nofollow">http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/</a><wbr>faqenglish.html
```

I am guessing it's due to the fact that it uses  and not . Should I replace the former with the latter? Looking for inputs from people who're familiar with wbr tag.

Comment: This sounds like a feature request/bugreport. Have you tried to contact wordpress.org for your support options in this case? Documentation of the WBR HTML tag is available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr

Comment: @hakre no, I haven't yet contacted wordpress support yet. I tried all the variations <wbr>, <wbr></wbr>, <wbr />. In all cases, the link gets broken. Definitely need to file a bug  report. It may not be wordpress directly, it could be the TinyMCE editor. I'll figure it out and file a bug with appropriate project. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely the user in question has the administrator role, and still has the dangerous `unfiltered_html` capability.

Because of this, the `<wbr>` tag is not stripped out by the security filters, and is left as is, causing your problems. Either remove this capability or demote the user to a non-admin e.g. an editor.

As for the `<wbr>` tag itself, it's a standard HTML tag, not part of a plugin. It indicates to the browser an opportunity for a word break

https://html.com/tags/wbr/

> The `<wbr>` element is used to define a word break opportunity in a string of text. It is particularly useful when you wish to define word break opportunities in a long unbroken string of text that might otherwise break improperly.

So the `<wbr>` tag itself is not dangerous or problematic, and may even help the formatting of the content.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this on a test site. I added only this link to a post.

```
<a href="http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/faqenglish.html" target="_blank">http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/<wbr />faqenglish.html</a>
```

The result from the page source is:

```
<p><a href="http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/faqenglish.html" target="_blank">http://www.msrlm.org/mrlif/<wbr />faqenglish.html</a></p>
```

- Verify the site is using the latest WordPress version,
- Temporarily disable all plugins to rule out a plugin conflict,
- Switch themes to rule out a theme problem.